# Adding AC adapter to solar powered device

Tags: battery-charging, solar-cell, charger, adapter

I have a solar-powered LED number display whose rechargeable batteries have apparently died. I'd like to hook it up to AC power using a 3V adapter (i.e., cutting the leads from the batteries and soldering to the adapter output), but I'm unsure whether anything special needs to be done to prevent the charging circuitry from frying the adapter. Presumably a simple diode would solve any such problem, but do I need to worry about it in the first place?

Comment: Is it one of [these solar powered displays](http://cfnewsads.thomasnet.com/images/large/593/593230.jpg)?

Comment: @jippie - not quite. More like [this](http://www.solarilluminations.com/acatalog/hn02_solar_house_number_light.html).

Comment: Why not just buy a couple of AA Nicad cells and replace the dead ones?

Comment: @JImDearden - because then I'll be repeating the task in two years, when they die again... (There isn't much sun in the spot it's mounted, so the batteries probably aren't getting fully charged.)

Comment: ok - then a 3V DC supply with diode should do the trick.

Comment: @JImDearden - my question is whether that's necessary. Will a few mA from a solar cell ruin a typical wall wart transformer?

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing the schematic of the wall wart. Also, are you sure the wall wart is regulated?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - good question, I hadn't thought of that. You mean that the voltage might be too high since it's only drawing a small amount of current?

Comment: I mean that the voltage may read 3V when a DMM is set to read VDC, but there could actually be a large amount of ripple (which a battery would of course not produce).

Answer (score 1):

Just use the adapter and cut the leads from the solar panel.

If the batteries "took over" supplying energy at night time then you needn't worry about the solar charging circuit affecting the batteries when dark and this applies if you power from an external 3V.

Cutting the leads from the solar panels stops any charging circuit causing any possible problem and emulates the night-time scenario. If you don't want to cut the leads from the solar panels, mask them off optically.

Comment: The problem is that the numbers will then be lit 24/7. I would like to retain the switching functionality of the solar panels to cut the power during the day, while avoiding any issues that may arise from the panels' charging during the night.

Comment: @kurkevan Are you saying that the LEDs are dimmed during the day by the presence of light on the panel irrespective of the charge of the batteries?

Comment: yes; the lights only come on at night